# markup specific strings in Xml

Tags: java, xml

I like to markup some strings in an xml document.

For example, I have:

```
<p> I like to go to Florida </p>
```

I need to tag the string "go" and have the output as:

```
<p> I like to <something>go</something> to Florida</p>
```

What is the best way to do this? I am using Java. I need to treat the XML file as XML not as text. I found some solutions that treat an xml file as a text file and use string.replace but I do not think those are good solutions.

Any suggestion is much appreciated.

Thank you,

Comment: You will need String.replace() somewhere. Even if you make a (really hard to understand) XSL-File. There will be some kind of String.replace(). If you know the XML-element whre the text is located, you could create a DOM / STAX Parser  and do the String.replace() only within that element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try an XSLT 2.0 transformation like this:

```
<xsl:template match="@*|*">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()">
  <xsl:analyze-string regex="go">
    <xsl:matching-substring>
      <something><xsl:value-of select="."/></something>
    </xsl:matching-substring>
    <xsl:non-matching-substring>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:non-matching-substring>
  </xsl:analyze-string>
</xsl:template>
```

You can of course extend the regular expression, e.g. regex="go|come|walk|run"; if you only want to match whole words, you might want to use tokenize() to split it into words and process each word separately.